# Preload marker images for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps V3 API to create a google map where the markers change their marker icons on mouseover. However i notice the icons flicker once the first time the user does it to that specific marker, and to every marker, which I guess is due to the mouseover images taking some time to download.

To solve this, I am thinking of preloading the mouseover icon images. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure if this works in every browser, but on modern browsers (FF 3.6+, IE8/9 (I think), Safari/Chrome), with cache enabled, simply adding the elements to the DOM loads them and caches them (i.e. put them on the page in a hidden div), so the next time they're requested, its from your cache, not the server, totally eliminating the flash.

Comment: Benno: How can I add to the DOM?

Comment: Putting them on the page puts them in the Document Object Model (which consists of ALL elements from the html tag to a lowly span or img tag). In your case, just do this: `<div style="display:none;"><img src="/path/to/marker/you/want/to/preload.png" /><img src="/path/to/marker2/you/want/to/preload2.png" /></div>`. When the browser renders your page, it requests those images from the server, and (usually) puts them in your cache. So the next time you request it (i.e. when you hover over the marker) it gets it instantaneously from the person's computer, not your server.