# Google Maps Api V3 - noticeable flicker when changing MarkerImage's URL

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I would like to change the marker image on a mouseover event. Right now, the important bit looks like this:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function (event) 
{
    this.set('icon', 'http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png');
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function (event) 
{
    this.set('icon', 'http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png');
});
```

There is a flicker when I mouse over the first time, which I think is because Maps is loading the new image from the URL.

Is there any way to pre-load both the yellow and red paddle markers and store them in cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Preload marker images for Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562607/preload-marker-images-for-google-maps), you can try putting the image URL in a `<div>` tag with CSS `display` set to `none` to sort of fool the browser into preloading it.

There may be other ways (HTML5 manifest?) but that would seem to be a quick and simple solution to try.  (If it doesn't work, it didn't take much effort to do and undo.  If you try it, I'd love to know if it works or doesn't work for you.)

In your case, you could do a quick-and-dirty test for it by including this on your page:

```html
<div style="display:none">
    <img alt="" src="http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the solution as you suggested and the image flickers once. It's still an improvement to have it, as without it there would be a pause where no marker would be shown.

Comment: Not quite perfect yet though. Once the marker images have been loaded, the transition is much smoother.

Comment: Anyone that finds this issue: the answer by Stuart Cusack fixed the problem for me much better (read: completely solved) than the suggested solution.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this solution will address your specific problem, but try disabling the "optimized" property of the marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long), 
   icon: markerIcon, 
   optimized: false
});
```

This fixed a problem for me in IE where hovering a marker at certain zoom levels would produce a flickering effect.

Comment: This actually fixed the proplem in ALL browsers. Read [inside the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de#MarkerOptions) why `optimized: false` works in such a case